# How to split data in one column into multiple columns based on duplicates in another column

Tags: excel

Is there a way to split data in one column into separate columns based on a duplicate cell, so that I only see 1 row for the data ex:

```
Column A   Column B    Column C

Gary          1         Gold

Gary          1         Silver

Gary          1         Bronze
```

How I need it to display:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C   Column D    Column E

Gary          1         Gold       Silver      Bronze
```

Any help would be great !

Comment: Generally speaking, your original layout is the preferred layout.  It is the way Excel expects your data to be layed out, and works well with built in functions such as Countif/s, Sumif/s, etc

Answer (score 1):

Explanation - First table is the original table, paste unique names ( Gary, Ben) as transpose  in the next rows , insert the index match formula in cell below and drag down,write similar formula in next column and drag down.

use this formula  INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(F$2,$A:$A,0)+ROW(1:1)-1,0) or look for offset formula.
Column C contains gold,silver detail and column a contains names. F2 is gary pasted as transpose below

```
Gary    Ben [ transpose of all unique names]
formula formula
formula formula
```

Then copy paste table e:f as transpose values to get the desired layout

Comment: You wouldn't have an example of a dummy counter variable and concatenation as you mentioned do you?  Excel Rookie here unfortunately....